# How to get second highest salaried employees in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an employee table in MySQL with below entries. I need to find all the employees having second highest salaries. In this case, it would be c and d.

```
id | name | salary
 1 |    a | 1000
 2 |    b | 1000
 3 |    c |  500
 4 |    d |  500
 5 |    e |  400
```

I tried running below query

```
SELECT name, MAX(salary) FROM employee WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) from employee);
```

But this query returns just c as a result. How to get both c and d in result?
I looked at bunch of similar questions posted but none of them mentioned how to get multiple rows for second highest salary.

Comment: I supposed that if there is another salary, for example C2, with salary 500 too, you need to show this salary too rigth?, so for this specific example you need to return 3 result's right ?.

Comment: yes, then it should return c,d and c2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by this:

**2nd Largest Salary:**

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees))
```

**3rd Largest Salary:**

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees)))
```

**Helpful links:**
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/select-nth-highest-record-database-table-using-mysql.aspx
http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/
http://www.coderanch.com/t/530503/JDBC/databases/select-Nth-highest-salary-table

Comment: This has two nested queries. Isn't there any better solution than nesting? What if I need all the employees with third highest salary?

Comment: @bestrahul21: i think its better solution, u can also write using Limit but value can vary, depends upon database. If you get any better solution, please post it

Comment: @bestrahul21: Updated the answer, have a look

Answer (score 3):

You can esily get second highest salary from table

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee WHERE Salary NOT IN ( SELECT Max(Salary) FROM Employee);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the second highest salary with:

```
SELECT salary 
FROM employee
GROUP BY salary
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1, 1
```

Then either feed the result of that to another query in the same transaction:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE salary = ?
```

Or do it as a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE salary = (
    SELECT salary 
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY salary
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1, 1
)
```

Comment: I appreciate that GROUP BY optimises better than DISTINCT - but it's kind of icky don't you think?

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't think of DISTINCT; that will work, too. I don't know which will optimize better, a good query optimizer should make them identical. As far as being "icky", both seem fine.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want migrate to MSSQL Server :).

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT MAX(salary) T,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS RankBySalary FROM Employees
GROUP BY SALARY ) TB 
WHERE RankBySalary = 3
```

Or much better:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ID,NAME,SALARY,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS RankBySalary FROM employee
)
TB  WHERE RankBySalary = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   SELECT *
   FROM employee one1
   WHERE ( N ) = (
           SELECT COUNT( one2.salary )
           FROM employee one2
           WHERE one2.salary > one1.salary
        )
```

> Note : N means Nth highest salary

**[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ff5a/73)**

Comment: What is N?  It happens to work for N = 2, but N = 1 and N = 3 return nothing.

Comment: Unknown column 'N' in 'where clause'

Comment: `N means Nth highest salary` @CanCelik Check demo link

Answer (score 1):

First find the second highest salary amount then select the rows having that salary.

**Query**

```
select * from Employees 
where Salary = (
  select min(t.salary) from (
  select salary
  from Employees
  group by salary
  order by salary desc limit 2
  )t
);
```

### <kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/682b23/1)</kbd>

Comment: If you're using min, why bother with limit.

Comment: @strawberry order by salary desc will give the top 2 salaries. Min among those 2 will give the second highest.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you must first select the 2nd highest salary first and then use the derived table with `JOIN` on original table. like this:

```
SELECT
  original_record.*
FROM
salary_record AS original_record
JOIN
(SELECT
  distinct salary
 FROM
  salary_record
 ORDER BY 1
 LIMIT 1,1
) AS derived_record
ON
 original_record.salary = derived_record.salary
```

PS: I have renamed your `employee` table as `salary_record` table

Also have a look at Varoon Sahgal's article on *Nth highest salary*, here: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/ .  The comments-section of this article as well as the article itself has some optimized examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name,max(salary) from employee x where (n-1)=(select count(distinct salary)from employee y where x.salary<y.salary);

Nth max salary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    -- IF THIS TABLE EXISTS, DROP IT
    DROP TABLE E2;      



    -- THE FOLLOWING CTE ARRANGES SALARIES IN DECENDING ORDER
    WITH copytable(Salary) AS
    (
        SELECT Emp1.Salary
        FROM Employees AS Emp1, Employees AS Emp2
        WHERE Emp1.Salary > Emp2.salary 
        GROUP BY Emp1.Salary
    ) 
    --  COPY THE CTE IN A TABLE 
    SELECT * INTO E2 FROM copytable     

    -- GIVES THE RANK TO THE SALARY IN DECENDING ORDER
    ALTER TABLE E2
    ADD  RankOfSalary INT IDENTITY(1, 1)    

    -- TO GET THE LOWEST RANK WHICH WILL BE THE HIGHEST SALARY
    DECLARE @rankOfSalary int;
    SELECT @rankOfSalary = COUNT(Salary) from E2; 

    --  SELECTING THE SECOND LARGEST SALARY
    DECLARE @SelectSalary INT
    SELECT @SelectSalary =  Salary from E2 where RankOfSalary = @rankOfSalary - 1;
```

THIS IS HOW YOU DO IT WITHOUT USING max(), order by, top in sql server
to select second largest salary of employees without using max(), order by, top in sql server

*JUST WANTED TO POST THIS :p*

Answer (score 0):

try this TO GET BOTH c AND d

```
SELECT 
  name, salary
FROM
  employee
WHERE salary = (
    SELECT salary
    FROM employee
    GROUP BY salary
    ORDER BY salary DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
);
```

Comment: start and offset needs to be dynamic. as it can have three max salaries and 5 second max salaries.

Comment: Those queries show the X highest paid employee, not the X highest unique salary.

Comment: use of limit is obviously not the right solution as @Jigar mentioned it would need to be dynamic

Comment: Now this gets a and b, the highest salaries.